# Can't find music purchased

Tags: google, google-play-music

Had a Motorola x phone which was defective.  Lost over 100 songs purchased through Google  play. I now have a Samsung  7 edge.  How can I find these purchases and download  them on this phone?  Please, please, please  help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the Google Play Music app available from the Play Store.  You should be able to sign right in to it and access all of your songs and playlists right away.

Comment: (just make sure you use the same username / credentials as you did on the last phone)

Comment: Hadn't  thought of  that. That might  be  my problem. Thank you  so much